# How to show a particular div based on radio box checked in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have radio buttons and 'delete' text with ng repeat,here based on radio button checked I need to show the delete text,whenever I click on radio button 'delete' text should show and again when I click to next radio button 'delete' should hide for previous unchecked radio button and should show for next checked radio button.
For me its working but onclick of next radio button previous 'delete' text is not hiding.Code is given below.Can anyone help me I am new to angularjs.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.div_ = [];

  $scope.items = [{
      id: 1,
      title: "first item"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "second item",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "third item",
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li style="color:red;display:inline" ng-click="item=1"><input type="radio" name="samename" value={{$index}}></li>
    <li style="color:blue;display:inline;margin-left:100px;" name="samenaame" ng-show="item==1" ng-show="item==1">delete</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do minimum amount of changes to your main code, but I think it is flawed.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the multiple ul's you had, so I removed them.

You can use ng-repeat-start and -end as in this example, maybe that's what you want.

This code will only show one extra "li" depends on which ID you selected. (using a "helper" property)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.div_ = [];
      $scope.selectedItem;//or nothing
      
      $scope.items = [{
          id: 1,
          title: "first item"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "second item",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "third item",
        }
      ];
      
      $scope.handleClick = function (item) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat-start="item in items" style="color:red;display:inline" ng-click="handleClick(item)">#Item={{item.id}}
<input type="radio" name="samename" value={{$index}}>
</li>
        <li ng-repeat-end style="color:blue;display:inline;margin-left:100px;" ng-show="selectedItem==item">delete #{{item.id}}</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: Its working fine but in my json inside $scope.items may not contains id,that I have written just for example,in that case how do we need to do

Comment: You can simply remove the ID then, you can use the object itself. @Aprasad

Comment: @Aprasad I see you are not marking any of your questions as answers, perhaps you don't know how to do it? There is a "V" mark next to an answer. It is highly recommended to mark answer that helped you with your question to motivate developers to help.